# I'm new to PHP and my code gives Notices

Tags: arrays, php

```
$site=file_get_contents("$link");

$price='#<span class=price>(.*?)<\/span>#si';

preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);

echo $pricelist[0]."<br>";

echo $pricelist[1]."<br>";

echo $pricelist[2]."<br>";
```

---

Hello all, i am new in PHP. i am trying to take price list from another website. I tried to write this code and it said "Notice: Array to string conversion in". How can i take this prices to the list like :

```
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $pricelist[0] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $pricelist[1] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $pricelist[2] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $pricelist[3] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $pricelist[3] ?></td>
</tr>
```

And also this code worked :

```
<?php

$site=file_get_contents("$link");

$price='#<span class=price>(.*?)<\/span>#si';

preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);

for ($a=0; $a<5; $a++){

echo $pricelist[1][$a].'<br>'; }

?>
```

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: whats the problem to it in for loop since you get multidimensional array

Comment: Notice how you're using `$pricelist[0]` in the not-working code, and `$pricelist[1][$a]` in the *working* code?

Comment: [*"HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions."*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/265575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pricelist[0]` (or any index for that matter) is apparently an array. This is confirmed by the code you posted that worked. So you need to determine how you want to output that array. A simple solution would be to use `print_r`

```
<tr>
   <td><?php print_r($pricelist[0]); ?></td>
   <td><?php print_r($pricelist[1]); ?></td>
   <td><?php print_r($pricelist[2]); ?></td>
   <td><?php print_r($pricelist[3]); ?></td>
   <td><?php print_r($pricelist[3]); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this--

```
$site=file_get_contents("$link");

$price='#<span class=price>(.*?)<\/span>#si';

preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);

echo "<tr>";

for ($a=0; $a<5; $a++){

echo "<td>".$pricelist[1][$a].'</td>'; 
}
echo "</tr>";
```